# How to convert NSData to NSString in Japanese

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdata

When I convert NSString to NSData, after convert from NSData to NSString

```
NSString *input = @"ステータス";
NSData *output = [NSData dataWithBytes:[input UTF8String] length:[input length]];
NSString *output2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:output encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The output2 is nil.
If input is alphabet character, it ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct conversion is

```
NSData* output = [input dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The problem with your code is that `[input length]` gives the number of Unicode characters, not the number of UTF-8 bytes.

Comment: While your answer is the best solution, I think another would be to replace `[input length]` with `strlen([input UTF8String])`.

Comment: @rmaddy: NSString *may* contain NUL-characters, and then strlen() would shorten the string. But that case is probably more of academic interest.